# Quaternions, txt file parsing, animation/graphing

Tags: python, animation, scripting, quaternion

Here's the setup:

I have text files that have timestamped translation (X, Y, Z) and rotation (X, Y, Z, W) data.

I need to turn this data into something useful.  A graph or an animation would be great, but even plotting these data points into a scene would be helpful.

Something to make quaternions relatable to some form of understood human-readable measurement would be ideal.

Anyway, here's what my data looks like.

```
<rdf:li>Thu 2016.04.28 at 11:58:02:139 AM EDT</rdf:li>
<rdf:li>Translation X Coordinate: -3.2085694110362977</rdf:li>
<rdf:li>Translation Y Coordinate: -1.197867039253428</rdf:li>
<rdf:li>Translation Z Coordinate: 0.48078423909602214</rdf:li>
<rdf:li>Rotation X Coordinate: 0.22961249490971072</rdf:li>
<rdf:li>Rotation Y Coordinate: 0.21702063175390662</rdf:li>
<rdf:li>Rotation Z Coordinate: 0.6846872482993578</rdf:li>
<rdf:li>Rotation W Coordinate: 0.6567979290396148</rdf:li>


<rdf:li>Thu 2016.04.28 at 11:58:02:144 AM EDT</rdf:li>
<rdf:li>Translation X Coordinate: -3.214916998318956</rdf:li>
<rdf:li>Translation Y Coordinate: -1.1993618771091203</rdf:li>
<rdf:li>Translation Z Coordinate: 0.4799950000327235</rdf:li>
<rdf:li>Rotation X Coordinate: 0.2288923548191825</rdf:li>
<rdf:li>Rotation Y Coordinate: 0.21741372305589235</rdf:li>
<rdf:li>Rotation Z Coordinate: 0.6856134027700572</rdf:li>
<rdf:li>Rotation W Coordinate: 0.6559526087106968</rdf:li>
```

I'm almost entirely clueless about how to go about any of these steps; large or small.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! This is a Q&A site much more like a Wiki than a forum, so it tends to be difficult to deal with very broad, or very specific questions. BlenderArtists is likely to give you much better answers, in your case, because so many of your initial questions will be very broad, and the later parts will be much too specific to be of any use to anyone else.

Comment: That being said, if there is something specific that you've tried, but don't understand we might be able to answer that.

Comment: To avoid being ENTIRELY unhelpful, I will say that Blender's recently added Animation Nodes will likely be helpful to you. You will probably also have to do some scripting to tell Blender how to use the data.